# How can I use the data from an adaptive Card?

Tags: c#, botframework, botframeworkemulator

I have a chatbot that sends an adaptive card asking a question that looks like this.
[Adaptive Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXQAa.png)

When an option is pressed, I want to be able to use the data from this card inside of my code.
The JSON file for my card is this:

```
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "speak": "Somone is trying to take your session.",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Someone is taking your session!"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Allow",
      "data": {
        "Value": "allow"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Deny",
      "data": {
        "Value": "deny"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know the bot is receiving something from the card as the event `OnMessageActivityAsync` is being raised. When I use this bot in the bot framework emulator, it shows here that it IS returning a value.
[JSON Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndYdX.png)

How can I use this data in my program for a task such as deciding whether the session can be taken in C#?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved It by using

```
var val = turnContext.Activity.Value;
            string value = Convert.ToString(val);
            return value;
```

I was using strings and because of the conversion issue I could not find how to access this. By switching it to `var` solved the issue.